# Use the intermediate value theorem and the hint to prove that any polynomial of odd degree must have a real root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Use the intermediate value theorem to prove that any polynomial of odd degree must have a real root. [ hint you need two cases one for positive infinite and other for negative infinite]

I do not know how can I use the hint , I find a lot of explanation for this question but they did not use two cases , could you please help me with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of odd degree and assume that the highest coefficient is postive. Then $\lim_{x\to \infty}p(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=-\infty$. So there exists an $x_1$ such that $p(x_1)<0$ and there exists an $x_2$ such that $p(x_2)>0$, moreover we may assume that $x_1<x_2$. By the intermediate value theorem we have that for each $y\in (p(x_1),p(x_2))$, there exists an $x\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $p(x)=y$. In particular this holds for $y=0$.

If the highest coefficient is negative you can use the same type of reasoning, but the limits in the beginning are switched.

Comment: thanks for that , do you mean lim x→+∞ p(x)= -∞ and lim x→-∞ =+∞ and every thing still the same like x1<x2

Comment: Yeah, but $p(x_1)>0$ and $p(x_2)<0$, it doesn't make any difference though.